# Hive: Create table from text file. Handle special character

Tags: hive, hdfs, hql, hiveql

I have data file in txt format which i need to load to a hive table[image: Data Sample]

I created a table to load data from this file and then LOAD command to insert data as shown below

```
    CREATE TABLE dev.table
    (Date string,
    c1 string,
    c2 string,
    c3 string,
    c4 string,
    c5 string,
    c6 string,
    c7 string,
    c8 string) 
    row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'filepath.txt'  OVERWRITE INTO TABLE dev.table;
```

The data is getting inserted into table but there appears a special character in each column. Below is sample data

[image: Sample output data]

Please help to get rid of this special character.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: What version of hive are you using?

Comment: Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.3.0-235
FYI. I can't make any admin changes to the system as it is on our client's environment.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in `HIVE-CLI` too?

Comment: No. On hive CLI it appears fine, but when I check the length of values in date column it shows 21 instead of 10. It is considering these special characters to count length.

Comment: Did you skip header?

Comment: Yes, Later I tried below table properties, but still, it didn't work.

         ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "separatorChar" = "\t", "quoteChar" = "\"" ) 
        STORED AS TEXTFILE tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");

Comment: Where are you running  those queries?

Comment: Hive CLI.
Well I figured out the solution. The problem was with file encoding. It was utf-16le encoded which i converted to utf-8 and then loaded it in the table.
Thanks for your efforts @karma4917

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query:

```
select Date from dev.table limit 10
```

As the data which you are selecting is in `dev.table`.

Comment: I did that only. I had edited the table names while putting the question.

Comment: Please if possible send me all the queries in sequence I will try because output should not be like this Or else try to skip header using following line in create table tblproperties(“skip.header.line.count”=“1”)